# Missing build file when building for rtl8812au driver

Tags: driver, wireless-adapter

I am trying to install a driver for a wireless adapter I have.

I am using `amped-wireless-aca1-linux` driver on github.

Hoping it should work on a raspberry pi as well.

I get the following error when trying to build it

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.13-v7+/build     M=/home/pi/rtl8812au  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.4.13-v7+/build: No such file or directory.      Stop.
Makefile:1052: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

I figured, oh, maybe some part of the raspberry pi doesn't make this compatible. So, I then tried [rtl8812au](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au) driver. Same error. Even with the flag active [here](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au/commit/6ef077f0d9164fddc551c89b0dbde7f5e1dada48)

I am not sure how I suppose to build the specific module for the wireless adapter. I have done `update, upgrade and rpi-update`

The directory of /lib/modules/4.4.13-v7+/ contains

`kernel/         modules.alias.bin  modules.builtin.bin  modules.dep.bin  modules.order    modules.symbols
modules.alias  modules.builtin    modules.dep          modules.devname  modules.softdep  modules.symbols.bin`

It is obviously looking for a build directory, but in the /lib/modules/4.4.13-v7+/ there is no indication one can be built. So, either something needs to be added or it is done elsewhere independently.

- sorry not enough rep for links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build this module from source, I did the following on my RPI2.

Install build tools:

```
# apt install build-essential bc git wget
```

Get kernel source code

```
# cd /usr/src
# git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux.git
# ln -s linux $(uname -r)
# ln -s /usr/src/linux /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build
```

Prepare linux build headers

```
# cd linux
# wget -O Module.symvers https://raw.githubusercontent.com/raspberrypi/firmware/master/extra/Module7.symvers
# KERNEL=kernel7
# make bcm2709_defconfig
# make prepare
# make modules_prepare
```

Download driver and build, (replace the module with the one you want build)

```
# cd ~
# git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
# cd rtl8812au
# KERNEL=kernel7
# make
```

Install

```
# make install
```

NOTE: the above should work for RPI2/3, check [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md) for the KERNEL and Module.symvers file.
BTW: I've build this ko on RPI2 on 4.4.13-v7+, you can download it from my [dropbox](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38684693/tmp/8812au.ko)

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. I am also trying to get [this](https://github.com/psaintlaurent/amped-wireless-aca1-linux/blob/master/Makefile) driver to build as well. It uses a modified version of rtl8812au. I did exactly the same thing and made the make file compatible with RPI using [this](https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au/commit/6ef077f0d9164fddc551c89b0dbde7f5e1dada48). I am still having errors building it for this specific driver.

Comment: I get this [error](https://ghostbin.com/paste/orhna). I change the makefile to make it go into the correct directory and I get even more errors. So, that possibility isn't the correct approach, to manual rewire the paths.

Comment: [Error](https://ghostbin.com/paste/fnya5) when I modify Makefile with new path.

Comment: @DKJ the first error looks like arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc is not in your PATH, I am not cross compiling it. Doing this on RP2 only takes few minutes. The second error just you are not using the right path.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed this and a few other pages to install the usb wifi device (RTL8821AU/RTL8812AU) - the right method is documented by  MrEngman on https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=66499&start=175. Go all the way to page 8 for the correct link since the dropbox link expired. I pasted the steps below. It takes 1 minutes to see wifi alive (ifconfig), whereas all other solutions consumed me 2+ days in vain (ex
: installing many packages and updating all the libraries). My USB has ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp with > lsusb command.

1. sudo wget http://www.fars-robotics.net/install-wifi -O /usr/bin/install-wifi
2. sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/install-wifi
3. sudo install-wifi -h (remove -h to run the installation)

Answer (score 0):

In Makefile you must edit line:

```
CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = n
```

to:

```
CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = y
```

and

```
CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = y
```

to:

```
CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n
```

This will enable configuration for Raspberry Pi.
Also you need to install kernel-headers:

```
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

Comment: I did this and still get the following error: `make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.4.13-v7+/build M=/home/pi/rtl8812au  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.4.13-v7+/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:1052: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
`

Comment: Check my edit about installing kernel headers.

Comment: currently doing it now. takes a while. Will edit with more news.

Comment: I installed the kernel headers. I still get the same error. It wants the build directory, but nothing in libs/modules/... shows anything to build one.

Answer (score 0):

That procedure works for me.

1) Update your raspberry pi

```
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

2) Restart your system

```
sudo reboot
```

3) Get the firmware from this repo

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
```

4)Modify the Make file according to with your system

```
sudo nano Makefile

CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n

CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = y
```

5) Compile

```
sudo make
```

6) Installing

```
sudo cp 8812au.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
```

Answer (score -1):

Does the driver have a cmake? .It may have cmakelist file. Try this, create a build directory then on command prompt go to the build directory and type "cmake .." without the quotes. Then type make.

Comment: There is no cmake related files when I download the driver.