# Install drivers for RTL8812au wireless usb adapter

Tags: wireless-adapter, make

I'm trying to install the RTL8812au drivers for a wireless usb adapter.  My error is very similar to another question.

[Missing build file when building for rtl8812au driver](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50240/missing-build-file-when-building-for-rtl8812au-driver)

However, the solution does not work for my version kernel version 4.4.50-v7 (found by running `uname -a`)

I configure the Makefile to `ARM_RPI=y` and `I386_PC=n` and run `make` then I get the following error.

`make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.4.50-v7+/build: No such file or directory. Stop.
Makefile:1052: recipe for target 'modules' failed`

Comment: See also: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/67719/19949

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Literally the very next thing I tried worked. I spent the last 5 hours working on this so I'll go ahead and share what I did to fix.

First, I sourced my drivers from the following github repo.

`sudo git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git`

`cd rtl8812au`

modified the Makefile

`sudo nano Makefile`

`CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n`

`CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = y`

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit and save

then ran

`sudo chmod +x install.sh`

This next step was critical for getting the make to work on my machine.  Before running `make` or `install.sh` I had to install raspberrypi kernel headers and build essential

`sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers build-essential`

then instead of manually running `make` I decided to use the automated install file.

`sudo ./install.sh` <--- This is where the error occurred before.  Now that you installed the RaspberryPi Kernel Headers it works.

Finally, I shutdown the device.  Plugged in my Realtek Wifi Adapter and booted it and it connected with my preset wifi settings.