# Install drivers for RTL8812au for raspibian kernel 4.14.79-v7+ or 4.14.79.87-v7+?

Tags: wifi, usb, realtek

I have bought this external [usb wifi antenna](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00H95C0A2) for my raspberry pi 3B+ that I would like to use instead the default one.

I see it is based on the realtek chipset as shown in `dmesg`

```
158816.385007] usb 1-1.1.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
[158816.515745] usb 1-1.1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=0811
[158816.515762] usb 1-1.1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[158816.515772] usb 1-1.1.3: Product: 802.11ac WLAN Adapter 
[158816.515780] usb 1-1.1.3: Manufacturer: Realtek 
[158816.515790] usb 1-1.1.3: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
```

I have followed the instruction of these forum posts ( [post1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64502/install-drivers-for-rtl8812au-wireless-usb-adapter) and [post2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67719/how-do-i-install-the-drivers-for-a-wifi-dongle-with-the-realtek-8812au-chipset-o)) to install the module for my adapter, but when I am trying to insert the module I get an error in the pi saying that the *module cannot be inserted*

Are those instruction still valid for my rapbian kernel 4.14.79-v7+ or 4.14.79.87-v7+ ? Or it should be easy just to update the raspian in the pi with `sudo rpi-update` and `sudo install-wifi -u rpi-update`?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

EDIT:

After using the script given by @jake I got this

```
pi@gf4:~ $ sudo git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au -b v5.2.20
Cloning into 'rtl8812au'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 6289, done.
remote: Total 6289 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 6289
Receiving objects: 100% (6289/6289), 19.77 MiB | 3.31 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4307/4307), done.
pi@gf4:~ $ cd rtl*
pi@gf4:~/rtl8812au $ sudo sed -i 's/CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = y/CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n/g' Makefile
pi@gf4:~/rtl8812au $ sudo sed -i 's/CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM64_RPI = n/CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM64_RPI = y/g' Makefile
pi@gf4:~/rtl8812au $ make
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.14.94-v7+/build M=/home/pi/rtl8812au  modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.14.94-v7+/build: Permission denied.  Stop.
Makefile:1550: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
pi@gf4:~/rtl8812au $ sudo make
make ARCH=arm64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.14.94-v7+/build M=/home/pi/rtl8812au  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/linux-049e03d71027297051bc19499082194ce64cdc91'
  CC [M]  /home/pi/rtl8812au/core/rtw_cmd.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mgeneral-regs-only’
scripts/Makefile.build:326: recipe for target '/home/pi/rtl8812au/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/pi/rtl8812au/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1535: recipe for target '_module_/home/pi/rtl8812au' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/pi/rtl8812au] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/linux-049e03d71027297051bc19499082194ce64cdc91'
Makefile:1550: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Comment: look at the **accepted** answer in those posts, not the repeated answer that seems to have zero upvotes - i.e. the answer you seem to have used because that's the only place that has this `sudo install-wifi -c rpi-update` rubbish

Comment: I use https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.git with the actual kernel. Did any errors occur while installing (building) the drivers?

Comment: What is 4.14.79.87-v7+ ? No such thing - the latest supported kernel is 4.14.79-v7+

Comment: Don't use `rpi-update` except you really know what you are doing. It will install untested developer versions and may make your system unstable.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

I seem to be hitting the same issue as well - getting error message with "gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-mgeneral-regs-only’"

Comment: I appear to have found a solution here - https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/issues/408

Answer (score 2):

This worked fine for my, so u suggest doing this step by step and then tell us, where it went wrong:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential raspberrypi-kernel-headers bc

sudo wget "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/notro/rpi-source/master/rpi-source" -O /usr/bin/rpi-source
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/rpi-source
sudo rpi-source 
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au -b v5.2.20
cd rtl*
sed -i 's/CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = y/CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n/g' Makefile
sed -i 's/CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM64_RPI = n/CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM64_RPI = y/g' Makefile
make
sudo cp 8812au.ko /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/drivers/net/wireless
sudo depmod -a
sudo modprobe 88XXau
```

Source: https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.

**EDIT**

In raspbian buster I made it working with the following commands. This will use `dkms` to install the driver, which will also recompile it automatically for every new kernel. So try this commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au
sudo apt install dkms
cd rtl*
sed -i 's/CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = y/CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n/g' Makefile
sed -i 's/CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM64_RPI = n/CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM64_RPI = y/g' Makefile
sed -i 's/^dkms build/ARCH=arm dkms build/' dkms-install.sh
sed -i 's/^MAKE="/MAKE="ARCH=arm\ /' dkms.conf
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Without adding `ARCH=arm` to `dkms-install.sh` the same error occurred, so that's worth a try.

Comment: I tried as you said and I got an error while invoking `make`, see edited post thanks!

Comment: @ndarkness with the commands in the edit it should work.

Answer (score 2):

What Jake said worked for me, HOWEVER, the latest version of Raspbian is 32bit instead of 64bit. Because of this, the lines starting in SED did not work. To have this done correctly:

```
sudo nano Makefile
```

(search for, or scroll down until you see 'arm')

Make sure that the y (yes) is on CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI instead of CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM64_RPI. Those three lines should look like:

```
CONFIG_PLATFORM_I386_PC = n
CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM_RPI = y
CONFIG_PLATFORM_ARM64_RPI = n
```

Save that change and you should be able to make without an error.

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar issue - see here:

https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/issues/408

The solution was to run the following two `sed` commands:

```
sed -i 's/^dkms build/ARCH=arm dkms build/' dkms-install.sh
sed -i 's/^MAKE="/MAKE="ARCH=arm\ /' dkms.conf
```

After that, I was able to run:

```
$ sudo ./dkms-install.sh
About to run dkms install steps...

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/5.3.4/source ->
                 /usr/src/rtl8812au-5.3.4

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
ARCH=arm 'make' -j4 KVER=4.19.66-v7+ KSRC=/lib/modules/4.19.66-v7+/build.............................................................
cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.

88XXau.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.19.66-v7+/updates/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
Finished running dkms install steps.
```