# Installing TP-Link AC600 High Gain Wifi on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: raspbian, wifi

My pi is running in my shed, quite a distance away from my house. It's working but I thought I would try and improve its wifi signal by purchasing a high-gain wireless adapter. I'm having a nightmare trying to install it though.

The output of `usb-devices` is the following:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2357 ProdID=0120 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11ac WLAN Adapter
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 6 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
```

So it's appeared to have found the device and can identify it, but it's not appearing in `ifconfig`. I just get `eth0`, `lo` and `wlan0`.

Output of `journalctl -b`:

```
Aug 20 11:17:33 enchantedtikished kernel: usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Aug 20 11:17:33 enchantedtikished kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=2357, idProduct=0120, bcdDevice= 2.00
Aug 20 11:17:33 enchantedtikished kernel: usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Aug 20 11:17:33 enchantedtikished kernel: usb 1-1.2: Product: 802.11ac WLAN Adapter
Aug 20 11:17:33 enchantedtikished kernel: usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Realtek
Aug 20 11:17:33 enchantedtikished kernel: usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
```

There are two things I am having trouble with:

1. Getting the adapter to appear as `wlan1`
2. Once it appears telling the pi to use `wlan1` over the default `wlan0`

I'm running Raspbian 10 (buster).

**Things I've tried**

- Spent a long time trying to compile the driver, but since `usb-devices` shows its there I shouldn't have to do that should i?
- Tried editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` to whats outlined here [USB WiFi adapter being detected but no connection](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9168/usb-wifi-adapter-being-detected-but-no-connection) - didn't work.

Comment: Try `ip -br link`. Do you find **wlan1**, maybe DOWN?

Comment: Thanks @Ingo there is no wlan1.

Comment: You wrote about *default wlan2*. What's that? Default is wlan0 for the built-in wifi device. For my understanding with `usb-devices` you only see the raw usb device that can be supported by a driver, so you have to load the correct driver. Look at `journalctl -b` if you find something about *firmware* or *driver* or *realtek*.

Comment: @Ingo sorry that was a typo. Using wlan1 (when I get it to register) over wlan0. I've updated the post with details  `journalctl -b`

Comment: You have to install the driver. Does this answer your question? [Install drivers for RTL8812au wireless usb adapter](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64502/install-drivers-for-rtl8812au-wireless-usb-adapter). Have also a look at [How do I install the drivers for a WiFi dongle with the RealTek 8812AU chipset on Raspbian?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/67719/79866).